# Pentaho Java API

Tags: api, datasource, pentaho

I am brand new to Pentaho and have the task of trying to integrate it into some Java applications I have been working on. So far my experience with Pentaho includes downloading the community BI-Server and setting up a couple of things in the admin console (new users/datasources). I was able to get access to the datasource in my PUC as well for reports and analysis.

Now I am trying to do practically the same thing in Java (Add a new datasource and configure it). I have been looking for different Java APIs and I must admit it is quite overwhelming with all the different APIs that are available (BI Platform, Kettle, Mondrian, Weka, Reporting). I decided to go with the BI Platform as this is the one that seems like it will fit this need. However the javadocs that are provided [here](http://community.pentaho.com/javadoc/) seem to be out of date. I have imported the 4.8.0 dependency into my Java project via Maven and it seems I do not have some of the classes that are specified in the javadocs. Pentaho's APIs will probably begin to make more sense the more I dig into them, but as an overwhelmed n00b I need help in the following three ways.

1) Is pentaho-bi-platform-api the correct API to connect to and administer datasources?

2) Are there any useful java examples of the API that I could look at? (havent been able to find much on Google)

3) Does anyone know if these javadocs are out of date and if so are there any more recent versions?

Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out a good place to get examples. If you go to http://community.pentaho.com/getthecode/ you can find all the SVN repositories for the projects. After pulling in the projects from SVN do an ANT build on the build.xml using the resolve function. After that I was able to look at all the Unit tests that are included in the project and figure out how everything works.

Answer (score 2):

Many of the Pentaho projects have been moved to GitHub:

https://github.com/pentaho

This includes the data-access plugin, which handles the creation and configuration of datasources.  The 4.8 branch is here:

https://github.com/pentaho/data-access/tree/4.8

And the latest 4.8 release tag (4.8.1-GA) is here:

https://github.com/pentaho/data-access/tree/4.8.1-GA